# Pass python flask object into jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

I have following jQuery which modifies my html code:

```
$('input[name="date-format"]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '0') {
        $(".date-range").html(`<div class="eu-input">
                                    <label>Date from</label><input name="eu-date-from">
                                    <label>Date to</label><input name="eu-date-to">
                                </div>`);
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == '1') {
        $(".date-range").html(`<div class="us-input">
                                    <label>Date from</label><input name="us-date-from">
                                    <label>Date to</label><input name="us-date-to">
                                </div>`);
    }
});
```

On the backend however, I have python flask and I am trying to pass flask-wtf form
within the modified html. Plain html and python code on the backend would look like this:

```
<div class="eu-input">
    <label>Date from</label>
    {{ form.eu_dates() }}
    <label>Date to</label>
    {{ form.eu_dates() }}
</div>


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    form = MyForm()
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

I am struggling to pass the python object into the JavaScript code and then include within the new html content.
Thanks for your help.

P/S:  I wouldn't wish to use .show()/.hide() method to achieve my goals because the forms are required and despite that they are hidden they still exist in the html code. This is my main reason for replacing the entire html code inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish, my guess is that you want to  change the date format based on user choice between:

1. DD.MM.YYYY
2. MM.DD.YYYY

And you have two form field, one for the US format and the other for the EU format.

If this the case you can render the two fields and wrap them in a div as follows:

```
    <div id="us-date-container">
        {{ form.us_dates() }}
    </div>

    <div id="eu-date-container">
        {{ form.eu_dates() }}
    </div>
```

and toggle their visibility using jQuery or JavaScript:

```
$('input[name="date-format"]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '0') { // show EU format
        $("#eu-date-container").show();
        $("#us-date-container").hide();
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == '1') { // show US format
        $("#eu-date-container")[0].hide();
        $("#us-date-container")[0].show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that the form fields are required and despite that they are hidden they still exist. They must not be part of the html code at all. That's why I'd prefer to replace the entire html inside the '.date-range' div if possible.

Comment: If both are required you can change the validation in the controller based on which date type is selected using `form.field.validators = []`